# devise with omniauth-google-oauth2 gem not returning google plus information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, google-authentication

I am trying to integrate omniauth-google-oauth2 gem in one of my rails application.

I have provided below configuration in my devise configuration file

config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "xxxx", "xxx", {:scope => "userinfo.email,userinfo.profile,plus.me"}

with the above configuration am able to login with google successfully but am not getting google+ work profiles, story, places and contact information.

It just giving me very basic google information it seems.

Can anyone please shed a light if there is anything wrong I did ?